# WPF Charts for OLAP Cubes

Tags: wpf, binding, wpftoolkit, mdx, olap-cube

Does anyone know whether there is any charting library or a way to integrate OLAP capabilities to charts done in WPF? What I want is to give a user an option to build charts on an OLAP cube by giving a specific MDX query he/she may wish and drill down the chart to explore the data.

Answer (score 0):

[Radarsoft](http://www.radar-soft.com/) has a set of components including an OLAP Grid and an OLAP Chart for WPF. I haven't used it myself, I only worked with the ASP.NET variant. But I think there is a trial version so you can see if it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks Rudolf. I have forgotten radarsoft. We have worked a little with their windows forms version. I will go ahead and look at their wpf offerings.